# create customized menu inside a layout in android?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

i am trying to customize my menu in my application to be shown from bottom side and the upper side. however, it can be shown like what i want with my design it will look like this[image]

but, what i want it look is like

[image]

so as you see in the second image

it appears from upper side and organized in bottom side
so what is the way to customize it?

Comment: show your some part of code which should be useful for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i discover that it is better to use custmized relativelayout and make it apper when we touch the scren and disappear when we touch again and it was the way to get this amazing feature wich i honestly recommend.

Answer (score 1):

set in Menu
  android:showAsAction="always"

Comment: That is discouraged, what would happen on a small screen phone? With less space?

Answer (score 0):

this is the menu layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     >

         <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
        android:title="مشاركة"
        android:showAsAction="always"



       />

         <item android:id="@+id/book" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
          android:title="حفظ علامة"
          android:showAsAction="always"





          />

         <item android:id="@+id/bookg" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
          android:title="انتقال الى العلامة"
          android:showAsAction="always"


          />

          <item android:id="@+id/adoaa" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_doaa"
          android:title="دعاء الختم"

          />

            <item android:id="@+id/ajzaa" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_ajzaa"
          android:title="الاجزاء"
          android:showAsAction="always"

          />

               <item android:id="@+id/work" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_applications_list"
          android:title="اعمالنا"
        android:showAsAction="always"

          />

                  <item android:id="@+id/fahrs" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_index"
          android:title="الفهرس"
      android:showAsAction="always"
          />

                     <item android:id="@+id/safhat" 
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_pages"
          android:title="الصفحات"
        android:showAsAction="always"
          />
</menu>
```